# Accessing cell value in SpatRaster, knowing column, row and layer

Tags: r, indexing, raster, terra

Good afternoon,

I have been using R's terra package, and have been looking for a way to access an individual cell's value.

I would have expected `raster_1[1, 2, 1]` for example, to return a numeric value telling me which value does the cell located on the 1st row of the 2nd column of the 1st layer have, but instead I get

```r
      mean
1 2.106639
```

Is this behaviour expected? What is this mean value anyway, shouldn't [row, col, layer] be returning one numeric value instead of a matrix?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: What's the name of the first layer? `names(raster_1)` ?  I would bet on "mean". Regarding returned types, you can check  ?terra::`[` ( ] in backquotes), but it's either a data.frame or the same type as `raster_1` (SpatRaster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @margusl, your result is showing your the expected value, but it has named that value with the name of the layer. Per the Terra [help doc](https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/subset_single.html), the syntax is `x[i, j, k]` where `i` is the row, `j` is the column, and `k` is the layer. We can make sure this is returning the expected results with a reproducible example.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.39
r <- c(
  rast(matrix(1:100, nrow=10, ncol=10)),
  rast(matrix(201:300, nrow=10, ncol=10)),
  rast(matrix(301:400, nrow=10, ncol=10))
) |> 
  setNames(c("layer1", "layer2", "layer3"))

r[1, 2, 1]
#>   layer1
#> 1     11

r <- setNames(r, c("mean", "a", "b"))
r[1, 2, 1]
#>   mean
#> 1   11
```

Just as in your example "mean" isn't referring to a function name, but to a layer name.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this! As stated before `names(raster_1)` returns "mean" (I do not know why though). I guess the behaviour is expected then (the return of a matrix)!